# Is there a way to control effort/torque in the DRC sim directly

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi
I am trying to control some of the drc robot. How can I give to the PID that is controlling the joint a set point of effort and not a set point of angle?

Thanks

Nachum

As said here I put into the launch file and the yaml an effort controller, when i do rostopic list I see the controller but when I give it a command nothing happens.

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/220/is-there-a-way-to-control-effort/torque-in-the-drc-sim-directly/) by [Nachum](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/50/nachum/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-11-14**:
You should probably update the title of this question to be more specific.  Something like: "Is there a way to control effort/torque in the DRC sim directly?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Currently effort controllers are not provided.

It's technically possible to change the controllers to any of the `robot_mechanism_controllers` but doing so may require tuning that is not straight forward. Though perhaps in the case of effort controllers that may not be the case.

<s>According to: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Roadmap DRC sim 1.1 will be released this Friday with support for a subset of the robot_mechanism_controllers, though what that means is not yet clear.</s>

None of the [recent commits to branch "default"](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/changesets) seem to show progress on this particular front, but it may be being developed on another branch so we'll have to wait for Friday to see I imagine.

*** update:
1.1 apparently did not include effort controllers ***

To switch controllers you need to make changes in two places:

1. the launch file where the `drc_robot_controllers-spawner` is started
2. a `yaml` file with the controller parameters

In principle it's as simple as replacing each instance of "position" with "velocity" or "effort".

<strike>I have an example `launch` file and `yaml` but cannot upload them since I don't have 60 karma yet, but I will do so once I can. On that note, if you select my answer I will get karma, and be closer to being able to do so.</strike>

- [`atlas_effort_controllers.yaml.jpg`](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13546735414700678.jpg)
- [`cam_effort_controllers.yaml.jpg`](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13546736377329825.jpg)
- [`drc_effort_robot-1.1.launch.jpg`](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13546736654292929.jpg)

Note: answers forced me to upload them as jpgs, with nondescript numbers for file names. You'll have to rename these as you download them to match the file names I give here. Also, you'll have to adjust the `rospack find` line in the launch file to match where you've stored these two yaml files.

---

Originally posted by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) with karma: 283 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/50/nachum/) on 2012-11-21**:
do you know if they realy released it with those controllers?

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/50/nachum/) on 2012-11-21**:
I downloaded drc sim 1.1 and it doesn't have tourque controllers

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-11-28**:
I've updated to the latest and do see torque controllers. Keep in mind they are labled as being "Effort" controllers

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-11-28**:
I recant. I cannot find the controller settings I thought I had seen.